# Как сделать отдельную cshtml страничку для login и register для identity в Asp Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Я создал asp.net приложение используя следующую строку

```
sudo dotnet new mvc --auth Individual -o WebApp1
```

И запустив проект я вижу такую страничку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не могу найти в проекте где определена эта форма.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во всех этих файлах нету описания ни для странички login, ни для странички register, но они существуют по такому маршруту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И опять же нету контроллера который бы принимал запросы с этого адресса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу без visual studio, так что не могу пользоваться его фичами.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего конечно же воспользоваться студией и создать нужные элементы через скаффолдинг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же студии нет - тогда используйте cli, вот тут примерно описано:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/59818745/5752652

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-3.1

То есть, смотрите какие файлы вообще можно заскаффолдить через `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles`, потом выбираете нужные и создаёте, например `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc ProjectName.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login"`

Comment: Не могу пользоваться dotnet aspnet-codegenerator.

```
No code generators are available in this project.Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package 
reference.
```

Даже после установки пакета