# Страничка с шаблонами код-генераторов .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Не могу пользоваться aspnet-codegenerator и visual studio, и потому не могу генерировать вообще никакой код. Есть где то все шаблоны, которые могут быть сгенерированны aspnet-codegenerator, чтоб я мог просто почитать их и понять что делать?

Comment: В данном случае я не могу решить проблему с этого вопроса
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222831/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-cshtml-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-login-%d0%b8-register-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-identity-%d0%b2-asp-n

Comment: Попробуй так: [aspnet-codegenerator: No code generators available, Even after adding Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64940810/2881286)

Comment: Я уже читал это. Не помогает вообще.

Comment: @Kemsikov а почему именно нельзя пользоватсья  aspnet-codegenerator? это же консольная тулза, она VS не требует.

Comment: Смотрите [руководства](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/samples-and-tutorials/), качайте [примеры](https://github.com/dotnet/samples) кода. По аналогии пишите код вручную, без генераторов.